# UWP App works in Visual Studio debug mode, but the release build won't run, missing DLL (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I made a very simple app which works perfectly in Visual Studio's debugger, but when I try to run it without Visual Studio, through the release build, the application will either just not run or crash and claim there's a missing DLL.

Here's my process:

- Clean Soluition
- Build Solution
- Deploy Solution
- Check "ProjectFolder/bin/x86/Release"
- Try to launch "ProjectName.exe", the wait wheel spins a little, but nothing happens
- Check the "AppX" subfolder in "ProjectFolder/bin/x86/Release"
- Try to launch "ProjectName.exe" in the "AppX" subfolder, but get error saying: "The code execution cannot proceed because SharedLibrary.dll was not
  found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." Then another
  error that reads: "The code execution cannot proceed because
  mrt100_app.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this
  problem."

I don't really know what I'm missing. Below, I will include my code. I'm really not doing anything complicated. This is literally my second application, the first being the "Hello World" app from a tutorial.

If you have any clues what I'm doing wrong, let me know. Thanks!

- Running Windows 10
- Using Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio Community 2017
- Need more info? Ask, and I'll get it for you.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Rando_Team"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Numerics="using:System.Numerics"
x:Class="Rando_Team.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d" Height="360" VerticalAlignment="Top">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="356" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Rectangle Margin="10,121,10,0" Stroke="#FFFDFEFF" Fill="#FFFDFEFF" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Rectangle Margin="10,0,10,129" Stroke="#FFFDFEFF" Fill="#FFFDFEFF" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    <Rectangle Margin="10,0,10,55" Stroke="#FFFDFEFF" Fill="#FFFDFEFF" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    <Rectangle Margin="10,0,10,18" Stroke="#FFF3FBFF" Fill="#FFF3FBFF" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    <Rectangle Margin="10,0,10,92" Stroke="#FFF3FBFF" Fill="#FFF3FBFF" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    <Rectangle Margin="10,158,10,166" Stroke="#FFF3FBFF" Fill="#FFF3FBFF" d:LayoutOverrides="TopPosition, BottomPosition"/>

    <Rectangle Height="32" Margin="10,84,10,0" Stroke="#FF6FC6F0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="#FF6FC6F0"/>

    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Generate" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,47,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button_Click" Height="32"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Height="32" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Number of boxes:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="125"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tfBoxes" Height="32" Margin="140,10,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" InputScope="Number" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="40,84,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Box" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="32" Margin="0,84,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Column" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy1" Height="32" Margin="145,84,115,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Row" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="40,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCol1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="32" Margin="0,121,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow1" Height="32" Margin="145,121,115,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="10,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="40,158,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCol2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="32" Margin="0,158,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow2" Height="32" Margin="145,158,115,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="10,158,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbBox3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="40,195,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCol3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="32" Margin="0,195,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow3" Height="32" Margin="145,195,115,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="10,195,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbBox4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="40,232,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCol4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="32" Margin="0,232,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow4" Height="32" Margin="145,232,115,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="10,232,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbBox5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="40,269,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCol5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="32" Margin="0,269,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow5" Height="32" Margin="145,269,115,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="10,269,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbBox6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="40,306,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCol6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="32" Margin="0,306,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow6" Height="32" Margin="145,306,115,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="10,306,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="10,84,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="#" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>

</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Rando_Team
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        int[] boxList = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        int[] rowList = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] columnList = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        int numberOfBoxes;
        Random r;
        int n;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            numberOfBoxes = 10;
            r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Second);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                boxList[i] = r.Next(1, numberOfBoxes + 1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                rowList[i] = r.Next(1, 6);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                columnList[i] = r.Next(1, 7);
            }

            updateTextBoxes();
        }

        private void updateTextBoxes()
        {
            tbBox1.Text = boxList[0].ToString();
            tbBox2.Text = boxList[1].ToString();
            tbBox3.Text = boxList[2].ToString();
            tbBox4.Text = boxList[3].ToString();
            tbBox5.Text = boxList[4].ToString();
            tbBox6.Text = boxList[5].ToString();

            tbRow1.Text = rowList[0].ToString();
            tbRow2.Text = rowList[1].ToString();
            tbRow3.Text = rowList[2].ToString();
            tbRow4.Text = rowList[3].ToString();
            tbRow5.Text = rowList[4].ToString();
            tbRow6.Text = rowList[5].ToString();

            tbCol1.Text = columnList[0].ToString();
            tbCol2.Text = columnList[1].ToString();
            tbCol3.Text = columnList[2].ToString();
            tbCol4.Text = columnList[3].ToString();
            tbCol5.Text = columnList[4].ToString();
            tbCol6.Text = columnList[5].ToString();
        }

        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (int.TryParse(tfBoxes.Text, out n))
            {
                numberOfBoxes = n;
            }
            else
            {
                tfBoxes.Text = "";
                numberOfBoxes = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot launch the UWP EXE directly. You need to deploy the app package, and then launch it from the app list/start menu.

Comment: Ah. I see. I guess I was confused which project type was which. I think I want the Windows Classic Desktop, not the Windows Universal. I just want to make exe programs. Windows store stuff isn't really what I'm shooting for right now. Thanks! I get it now.